# Are There Any RDBMS That Can Update or Insert In One Statement?

Tags: sql

If I have a table like this:

```
ID     FirstName     LastName     Address
--     ---------     --------     -------
```

I want to update info when there is an existing ID or insert a new row when the ID does not already exist.

Can this be done in one statement or do I have to check for the existance of the ID and then either insert or update?

Comment: Yes, most of them do -- either via `merge` or conflict resolution in `insert` statements.

Comment: It depends, tag the RDBMS you're using for an accurate answer

Comment: The answer is: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are three methods that come to mind:

`merge` is the most common method.  SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, and Teradata support this.  Refer to the appropriate documentation.  Note that the exact `merge` syntax may vary from database to database.

`on duplicate key update` is a method used by (older versions of) MySQL and MariaDB.  Refer to the appropriate documentation.

Postgres and SQLite supports conflict resolution via the `on conflict` clause in `insert` statements.  That said, many databases are based older versions of Postgres, so not all derived databases support `on conflict`.

(I apologize for databases not listed.  This is off the top of my head.)

If a database supports this functionality, then one of these three methods is probably used.  You can always use transactions to get similar effects using multiple statements.